# Issue with background images

Tags: sass

I have an issue where I can't get my background image to display. I am working in react and have webpack watching. The rest of the scss is working correctly though. From everything it looks like it should be working. My file paths look like this:
public > images > classroom.jpg
public > stylesheets > component >ReactWebPageBody.scss

```
.mainBody{
    height: 92vh;
    width:100vw;
    background-image: url('/images/classroom.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 }
```

I am getting GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/images/classroom.jpg 404 (Not Found)

my webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './public/app/ReactApp.jsx'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: './public/scripts'
  },
  devtool: 'sourcemap',
  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel'
        },
        {
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was running live-server because I didn't need node.js yet. Apparently, I ran it from the root folder and then clicked on the public folder to enter the project. whick=h is why I was getting the error. Once I quit live-server and started live-server inside the public folder on the command line it fixed the issue.